Convert '3' to numpy.dtypes.Int64DType
I have strings containing str representations of numpy values. I also have a list of the original dtypes, such as numpy.dtypes.Int64DType. I do not know all possible dtypes in advance. I can for the life of me not figure out how to convert the string back to a scalar of the correct dtype.
dt = numpy.dtypes.Int64DType
dt('3')  # I was somewhat hoping this would work but the dtype is not callable
np.fromstring('3', dtype=dt)  # ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
np.fromstring('3', dtype=dt, count=1)  # ValueError: string is smaller than requested size
np.fromstring('[3]', dtype=dt, count=1)  # ValueError: Cannot create an object array from a string

For the latter three calls, I also get a

:1: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is
deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use
frombuffer instead`

Which I don't understand, because '3' is not a binary string?

Int64DType looks more like a pandas extended dtypy, not a numpy one.

@hpaulj Yes I am working with pandas, but this is a numpy dtype and one should be able to create an instance of this dtype, no?

If you don't first import pandas can you use numpy.dtypes.Int64DType?  I don't have access to a python session to test this.  Can you use astype?  e.g. np.array(3).astype(dt)

@hpaulj Yes that works without issues, pandas is not required.

Why are you using dtypes classes?  What's the source of that list of 'original dtypes'?  np.fromstring('3', dtype='int64', sep=' ') is the usual format for reading a string.  Currently I have numpy 1.24 installed so don't have access to the newer dtypes module.  By the way fromstring doesn't work with strings like '[3]'.  It isn't a general purpose array creator.  '1 2 3' can make a 3 element 1d array, assuming the sep is right.  Don't count on fromstring to work with the new dtypes module.

@hpaulj I have string representations of elements from a pandas DataFrame that I later sometimes want to convert back to the original data types. So I use df.dtypes to obtain a dict of the applicable dtypes and was looking for a general method to convert the strings back to the original dtypes.

In pandas docs I find usages like dtype=pd.Int64Dtype().  The only distinctive in this dtype is the handling of missing values. Would the numpy dtypes class handle this? Where is this string representation coming from?  Loading a csv with array cell values?

I still don't quite understand why the above attempts did not work (or how I can tell fromstring that the input string is non-binary) and I don't find the error messages particularly helpful, but the following does what I want:
np.array('3', dtype=dt).item()

Edit: I overlooked the following note on the doc page, because I was not using the optional sep argument (it seemed irrelevant to the scalar case):

Deprecated since version 1.14: Passing sep='', the default, is deprecated since it will trigger the deprecated binary mode of this function. This mode interprets string as binary bytes, rather than ASCII text with decimal numbers, an operation which is better spelt frombuffer(string, dtype, count). If string contains unicode text, the binary mode of fromstring will first encode it into bytes using utf-8, which will not produce sane results.

Indeed, np.fromstring('3', dtype=int, sep=' ') works. However, np.fromstring('3', dtype=np.dtypes.Int64DType, sep=' ') still does not work and gives a ValueError: Cannot create an object array from a string.
Edit #2: Apparently, np.dtypes.Int64DType must be instantiated, different from standard dtypes. So: np.fromstring('3', dtype=np.dtypes.Int64DType(), sep=' ') works (note the added parentheses).

Initial attempts to convert string representations to NumPy dtypes failed due to mismatched tool usage. np.fromstring is optimized for binary data, while numpy.dtypes.Int64DType is a metadata descriptor. The solution involves using np.array to correctly interpret the string as numerical data and casting it to the desired dtype, followed by extracting the scalar value using .item(). This approach aligns with NumPy's core functionality.

np.fromstring('3', dtype=int, sep=' ') works because int is a standard dtype, and sep=' ' interprets '3' as an integer in text mode. However, np.fromstring('3', dtype=np.dtypes.Int64DType, sep=' ') fails because np.dtypes.Int64DType is not a standard dtype, and it is treated as an object dtype, which cannot be created from a string.

What does np.dtypes.Int64DType() display as?  Looks like  that would be an instance of np.dtypes.Int64DType class. That's different from something like np.int64 which is a function as well as a dtype

NEP42 talks about extensible DType classes.
